# Math Pow inside another math pow function in C#

Tags: c#, excel, math, pow

Im trying to translate an excel function :

```
10^(-0,2*7^2+2,74*7+(-4,72))
```

Which gives me the result = 45708,8

When i try to execute this in my application i get the wrong result everytime.. now im stuck at the result = 0

my c# code is:

```
destB = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, -0.2 * Math.Pow(Decimal.ToDouble(destB), 2.74 * Decimal.ToDouble(destB)+(-4.72)))
```

Comment: Your two formula's are not the same. The `C#` one goes like `10^(-0.2 * destB ^ (2.74 * destB - 4.72))`

Answer (score 1):

What is `destB`? The translated version:

```
Math.Pow(10, -0.2 * 7 * 7 + 2.74 * 7 - 4.72)
```

If `7` is `destB`, then:

```
Math.Pow(10, -0.2 * destB * destB + 2.74 * destB - 4.72)
```

Sample code:

```
double destB = 7;
double result = Math.Pow(10, -0.2 * destB * destB + 2.74 * destB - 4.72);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[C# Demo](http://rextester.com/YPC31508)

P.S. I don't do `Math.Pow(destB, 2)` since it neither improves readability, neither shortens code.

Answer (score 0):

This does it

```
Math.Pow(10,(-0.2* Math.Pow(7,2)+2.74*7+(-4.72)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the exact translation

```
var destB = Math.Pow(10, -.2 * Math.Pow(7, 2) + 2.74 * 7 + (-4.72));
```